# How to check if there is no smart-contract deployed on selected address?

Tags: web3js

For example if I want to warn my user that he make mistake in contract address.

Comment: Though this doesn't help if there _is_ a contract at the given address, but it's the wrong contract.

Comment: Should this question be edited to focus on Richard's second comment?  Otherwise this question is a duplicate of the other questions raised in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check whether an particular address contain some code just run below command from geth

> web3.eth.getCode (addressstring).
>   For more info https://googleweblight.com/i?u=https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html&hl=en-IN
>   Or you can simply check on etherescan.io